# Как отсортировать списки в списке(js)?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Есть список: `a=[[2,”a”], [1, “b”], [0, “c”]]`
Нужно отсортировать по нулевому индексу(то есть по числам)

```
a=[[0, “c”], [1, “b”], [2, “a”]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const a = [[0, 'c'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'a']];
a.sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);
console.log(a);
```

Подробности см.:

[`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)